# how to set initial letter caps in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

i am having problem in Initial Letter caps for my Amounts in words field with Crystal report 9.0...
can any one help
for Eg:

five lakhs fifty-four thousand fifty-nine only

for above eg. i want initial letter caps.

Like **Five Lakhs Fifty Four Thousand Fifty Nine Only**

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with version 9 of Crystal Reports you may use `ProperCase()`.
Reference to support above statement:  http://www.kenhamady.com/news0209.shtml

Example (in a formula field):

```
 ProperCase( my_field );
```

Result:

```
Five Lakhs Fifty-Four Thousand Fifty-Nine Only
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question answer is  Propercase({table.field})